# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes after login

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

Yesterday I installed Ubunted on my laptop (Dell XPS 15 9560) and the installation went fine. I plugged in the USB and created an ext4 partition, made a user with a password and everything.

Then I boot up Ubuntu, it takes me to the log in screen, I type my password, and then all the UI except the mouse (which is frozen) disappears and nothing happens.

I have tried reinstalling the desktop with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and udating the Intel graphics driver, both of which didn't help

(this is my first time asking a question here, so please go easy on me)

Comment: Hey, 9550 user here, so I'm pretty close. If you installed ndivia drivers, please uninstall them and try again. (via `apt-get remove nvidia-*`) reboot and try to reproduce the error. Once you're there please check your logs). on the login screen press CTRL+ALT+F5, login there and type `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. Once syslog is up, press CTRL+ALT+F2 again and try to login, if fails, switch to screen 5 again, and try to screenshot/phone-picture the logs and attach them to the question

Comment: Hi, I got it working on my own. I found out that it was throwing a bunch of errors, and i googled them and found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPprHes-K_Y and it fixed it. Nevertheless, thank you for taking the time to answer, and have nice day :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got it working on my own. It was throwing this error:

`NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 2`

`watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#* stuck for 22s!`

I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPprHes-K_Y and it solved my problem.

---

#### EDIT:

The video describes editing the grub configs. You can either do this by pressing 'e' while in grub menu or by dropping into recovery mode and editing the /etc/default/grub file:

To the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, add `nouveau.modeset=0`

Comment: could you describe what the video shows so that SO users can actually benefit from it? First, not everyone can watch youtube videos, and second, link-only answers are highly discouraged on SO.

Comment: The video describes editing the grub configs. You can either do this by pressing 'e' while in grub menu or by dropping into recovery mode and editing the /etc/default/grub file:

To the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, add nouveau.modeset=0

After trying 100 different configurations and changes and settings over 20hrs of work, THIS is what worked. Crappy answer just pointing to a youtube video, but still so glad it worked.

Comment: I encountered similar problem. The root cause is probably due to some issue with the Nvidia GPU driver. And resolved it with the suggestion in the answer of adding nouveau.modeset=0. More discussion on the issue at https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required